# Am I running my cron tasks in Heroku correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, heroku

Not sure if I am doing this right. Reading: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron#frequently-asked-questions

If I have cron running every 24 hours on Heroku. Will it run `def foo` and `def bar` every 24 hours? Or should I wrap both methods with `if Time.now.hour % 24== 0 # run every 24 hours`?

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do

  def foo
    puts 'foo'
  end

  deb bar
    puts 'bar'
  end

end
```

Second, how can I run this cron job on my local machine (possibly via console or other method)?

PS. I am running Rails 3.1 RC5 on the Cedar stack.

Comment: Why did you put the def's inside the task and not call them? I've never seen that before, will ruby execute your defs if they're inside the block you're running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've set up the cron as "daily" then it will run every 24 hours, there's no need to put an if statement in there.

To run the cron task locally just do `rake cron`

Edit:

You'll also need to call the methods you've defined in there as currently all your cron does is define foo and bar:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do

  def foo
    puts 'foo'
  end

  def bar
    puts 'bar'
  end

  foo
  bar

end
```